# Connect multiple strings efficiently

Tags: java, performance

I've got an interface IO, that offers two methods, void in(String in) and String out(). I've implemented that in a first, naive, version:

```
private String tmp="";
public void in(String in){
  tmp=tmp+in;
}
public String out(){
  return tmp;
}
```

I know this is an horrible implementation, if you have multiple, very long Strings. You need make a new String with length = tmp.length+in.length, copy tmp, copy in. And then repeat that again for evey inserted String. But what is an better implementation for that?

```
private List<String> tmp= new ArrayList<>() //maybe use an different list?
public void in(String in){
  tmp.add(in);
}
public String out(){
  return connect(tmp);
}
private String connect(List<String> l){
  if(l.size()==1) return l.get(0);
  List<String> half = new ArrayList<>();
  for(int i=0;i<l.size();i+=2){
    half.add(l.get(i)+l.get(i+1)); \\I have to check, if i+1 is valid, but this is just a draft ;)
  }
  return connect(half);
}
```

This is a bit better, it has to make the same number of String-connections, but the Strings are going to be smaller by averange. But it has an giant offset, and i'm not sure it's worth it. There schould be an easier option than this imho, too...

Comment: Perhaps [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) would suit...just `append` the input and call `toString` when you need the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be looking for a `StringBuilder`.

```
private StringBuilder tmp = new StringBuilder();

public void in(String in) {
    tmp.append(in);
}

public String out() {
    return tmp.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting me StringBuilder. I've never seen this clas before. But how is that implemented inside of StringBuilder? When i take a look at the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) , it tells me StringBuilder wants an initial capacity (or would guess 16 chars). Is StringBuilder still good for very long Strings (>3 million characters) ?

Comment: @alexberne - You should not worry about the implementation behind the scenes - that is premature optimisation and is considered [evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). If you are really growing a string to 3+million characters then you may wish to consider a file but so long as you have enough memory (perhaps even as much as twice the length of your string) it still should work.

Answer (score 0):

The standard library provides a class specifically for efficient string concatenation, the `StringBuilder`:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html

Note that the compiler will actually desugar your string "additions" into expressions involving StringBuilders, and in a lot of simple/naïve cases it will also optimize the code to make use of the `append()` method instead of constantly creating new StringBuilders. In your case, however, it is definitely a good idea to explicitly use a StringBuilder.

As for your adventurous attempt at optimizing the concatenation, I honestly don't think you will notice any improvements over the naïve solution, and clean code is always preferable to "slightly faster code", unless clock cycles are extremely expensive.

Answer (score 0):

From Java Doc:

> If your text can change and will only be accessed from a single
>   thread, use a StringBuilder because StringBuilder is unsynchronized.
>
> If your text can changes, and will be accessed from multiple threads,
>   use a StringBuffer because StringBuffer is synchronous.

In your case `StringBuilder` will work just fine.

> The StringBuilder class should generally be used in preference to this
>   one, as it supports all of the same operations but it is faster, as it
>   performs no synchronization.
>   http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html